# Finding substring in a string

Tags: c

I am writing a function to find substring. But I am not sure where i am going wrong.
On running GDB i get a segmentation fault. If someone can guide me in the right direction.

here is the code

```
char *mystrstr(char * s1, const char * s2)



int main(){
    char *s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the hell lazy dog";
    char *s2 = "hello";
    char *s4;
    s4 = mystrstr(s1,s2);
    printf("%s\n",s4);  <--- this is where i am Seg. Faulting



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not returning null?

Comment: @KRUKUSA. I think i am sure about it.

Comment: @Gluttton quick guess, it the OP's implementation of strlen

Comment: ... count till `'\0'` on each iteration ... bad idea

Comment: @Gluttton that is my function for strlen

Comment: Where do you *expect* to find the word `"hello"` in that sentence?? I don't see it in there at all!

Comment: @abelenky , if the word dsnt exist, it should just return null.

Comment: You *don't* see "hello" in your string, hence you *are* returning NULL.  Trying to printf() NULL gives a segmentation violation.  Please try J0rge's response, and "accept" his answer if it works.

Comment: @FoggyDay, since I am new user, cannot accept it before 5 - 7 minutes but yes it works.

Comment: Well then let me upvote your question :)  Please upvote J0rge and abelenky (and Amir, if you want).  Q: Can you "accept" now?

Comment: `i < mystrlen(s1)...s1[i+j]` : it exceed the valid range of sequence is present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When s2 is not a substring of s1 you are returning null, and then you are trying to print it, that gives a segmentation fault.

Try something like this:

```
s4 = mystrstr(s1,s2);
if(s4 != NULL)
    printf("%s\n",s4);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in the inner loop you add the indices `i+j` to access `s1`. If you imagine `i` to point to the "o" in "dog" in your example, `j` goes from 0 to 5 (length of "hello") in the inner loop. This causes your access to `s1[i+j]` to look at the characters `o`, `g`, `\0`, **garbage**, **garbage**.

The benefit of C strings is that they are null terminated. So you can iterate over strings like

```
for (char* i = s1; *i != 0; i++) {
    ...
}
```

I.e. you iterate from the start of `s1` until you find its terminating 0 byte. In your inner loop, this allows you to write the following:

```
const char *j, *k;
for (j = s2, k = i; *j == *k && *j != 0; j++, k++);
if (*j == 0)
    return i;
```

I.e. `j` starts at the beginning of `s2`, `k` starts where `i` is currently pointing at inside `s1`. You iterate as long as both strings are equal, and they have not reached their terminating 0 byte. If you have indeed reached the 0 byte of `s2` (`*j == 0`), you have found the substring.

Note that you probably want to return `i` instead of `s1`, since this gives you a pointer into `s1` where the requested substring starts.

Comment: As J0rge correctly pointed out, you stumbled across another issue with the code: Namely passing `NULL` to *printf*. However, my point above still holds and will give you nasty crashes in case you read past your string into a memory region that is protected by your CPU's memory management unit.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%s\n",s4? s4 : "(NULL)");
```

Comment: +1.  J0rge already gave one good solution that addresses the root cause.  This solution allows you to print something whether or not the string is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the hell lazy dog";
char *s2 = "hello";
```

According to `mystrstr` `*s2` is not substring of `*s1` because you cannot find `hello` in the `*s1`. Therefore, the method will return `NULL`. And printing `NULL` as a string is not possible and result in an error.

To verify this, try to replace `*s1` by:

```
char *s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the hello lazy dog"; // replace hell by hello
```

The output will be:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the hello lazy dog
```